# How to convert string to ByteString when using protobuf?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-csharp-port

I want to convert a string object to ByteString.I have tried to use  ByteString.CopyFrom() function to convert,but the return value is always "{Google.ProtocolBuffers.ByteString}".Why? How can I do?

[The function i use like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWkjs.png)

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGw87.png)

Comment: byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `string` has been successfully converted to `ByteStream`. If you see *{Google.ProtocolBuffers.ByteString}* in the watch window, it simply means that the `ByteStream` does not override the `ToString` method. In short, Visual Studio doesn't know how to display a `ByteStream`, and therefore just display the type name instead.

That said, there is an overload of the `CopyFrom` method that allows you to directly use a string:

```
var APP_DEF_TEA_KEY = ByteString.CopyFrom("e#>&*m16", Encoding.Unicode);
```

Comment: Got it!Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

According to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/byte-string#class_google_1_1_protobuf_1_1_byte_string_1a34312693c1a26482efd2aea46d8d4902), `Google.ProtocolBuffers.ByteStream`needs an encoding to know how to display its content. Use `ByteStream.ToString(Encoding encoding)` or `ByteStream.ToStringUtf8()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of methods from ByteString class to convert string to ByteArray
`ByteString.copyFromUtf8(stringText)`.